# How to terminate child process started from Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a Jenkins job which executes a jar. This jar starts another process from within it. On aborting[X] the Jenkins jobs from UI it is not killing the processes started on the slave machines, whereas on console it shows Aborted. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the job completely:

http://MY_SERVER/job/JOB_NAME/doDelete

Keep in mind that this will completely remove the current **build** and you will no longer have any access to it.